# mwheel-scroll bindings between GUI and terminal?

Tags: key-bindings, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, scrolling, mouse

Using an Emacs daemon (28, pgtk branch) switching between GUI and terminal, I can't get mouse scrolling to work on both. They work on each individually, but the issue is with the `mouse-wheel-{up,down}-event` var - it's `mouse-4/5` on terminal and `wheel-down/up` on GUI. This has been documented in bug-gnu-emacs as [far back as 2009](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2009-08/msg00387.html). I tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") (kbd "<mouse-down>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") (kbd "<mouse-up>"))
```

as suggested, but that gave me `bad binding in mwheel-scroll`.  Trying other things with kbd macros gave me `After 0 kbd macro iterations: undefined: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug to the feature/pgtk maintainer

> https://github.com/masm11/emacs/issues/108
> https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=50321

and it has just been fixed in

> https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=feature/pgtk&id=b22323c3b66feb3c9c0f3086cc784fab9578ff7b

---

**This is only a partial answer to the question.**

I recently upgraded to Emacs 28.0.50 with `feature/pgtk` to have better Wayland integration. Just like you I am connecting with both GUI and terminal clients to the same daemon, but scrolling no longer worked in the terminal.

I figured out that I need the following Elisp to restore scrolling in the terminal.

```lisp
(unless window-system
  (defun track-mouse (e))
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (when (featurep 'pgtk)
    (setq mouse-wheel-down-event 'mouse-4)
    (setq mouse-wheel-up-event 'mouse-5)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'mwheel-scroll)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'mwheel-scroll)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'mouse-wheel-text-scale)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'mouse-wheel-text-scale)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<S-mouse-4>") 'mwheel-scroll)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<S-mouse-5>") 'mwheel-scroll)))
```

Unfortunately, this only fires once, so it breaks scrolling for GUI clients. I tried to work around this using `focus-in-hook` and `make-variable-frame-local` but the former crashed Emacs when switching between frames and the latter is deprecated.

---

EDIT: I've managed to find something that seems to do what I want. Essentially I advise `mwheel-scroll` and `mouse-wheel-text-scale` to locally change the event type for scrolling when invoked through `mouse-4` and `mouse-5`. This is probably extremely inefficient but it seem to work.

```lisp
(defun track-mouse (e))
(xterm-mouse-mode t)
(when (featurep 'pgtk)
  (defun user/mwheel-scroll (&rest args)
    "Wraps `mwheel-scroll' for use with <mouse-4> and <mouse-5>."
    (interactive (advice-eval-interactive-spec
                  (cadr (interactive-form 'mwheel-scroll))))
    (let ((mouse-wheel-down-event 'mouse-4)
          (mouse-wheel-up-event 'mouse-5))
      (apply 'mwheel-scroll args)))
  (defun user/mouse-wheel-text-scale (&rest args)
    "Wraps `mouse-wheel-text-scale' for use with <mouse-4> and <mouse-5>."
    (interactive (advice-eval-interactive-spec
                  (cadr (interactive-form 'mouse-wheel-text-scale))))
    (let ((mouse-wheel-down-event 'mouse-4)
          (mouse-wheel-up-event 'mouse-5))
      (apply 'mouse-wheel-text-scale args)))
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'user/mwheel-scroll)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'user/mwheel-scroll)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'user/mouse-wheel-text-scale)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'user/mouse-wheel-text-scale)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<S-mouse-4>") 'user/mwheel-scroll)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<S-mouse-5>") 'user/mwheel-scroll))
```

Comment: I have also opened an issue about this: https://github.com/masm11/emacs/issues/108